# Searching via DataTable.Select, BindingSource and foreach (C#, ADO.NET)

Tags: c#, ado.net, select, datatable, bindingsource

I have a DataTable X, if I now want to search for a certain entry, would it be faster/better to use BindingSource.Filter, X.Select() or just foreach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment on performance, but your code will be most versatile if you use `X.Select()`, because you are operating directly on the source.

Also consider setting `X.PrimaryKey` and using `x.Rows.Find()` if the row you're searching for can be located by performing an equality comparison on one (or more) columns. This option is generally faster than the `Select()` method.